# Next.js + React Go back to the previous page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am use routing in next.js. How to implement a back button that navigates back to the previous page? Just like with the button on the browser.

Comment: You might want to check [Next.js getting started](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages) page.

Comment: looked but did not find a solution. I tried to do so but get constant page redirects. export const BackUrl = ({url}) => (
  <Link onclick={window.history.back()}>
    <a>
      <i className='ico-nazad ico' />&nbsp;
      <p>Nazad</p>
    </a>
  </Link>
)

Comment: [Client-Side History Support](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/navigate-between-pages/client-side-history) states: `When you hit the Back button, it navigates the page to the index page entirely via the client; next/link does all the location.history handling for you.You don't need to write even a single line of client-side routing code.`. So you don't need the `onClick` attribute with `window.history.back()`

Comment: @Дмитрий My aim is to prevent users from leaving my website. If a user is on another site, such as google.com, and manually enters my website's URL, this solution could lead to unintended redirection to the external site. In this case I would prefer to redirect them to the index of my website. Unfortunately I have not been able to determine how to implement this check. Any guidance or assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 180):

**EDIT**: 2 years after this answer was first posted, the router method is now [well documented](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerback). Here is the code straight from the documentation:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => router.back()}>
      Click here to go back
    </button>
  )
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

There is an undocumented `Router.back` method ([see source](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/d21603707edfaab292cb3190881efda9a07195cd/lib/router/router.js#L138)) that just does `window.history.back()`

You should have a component like so

```
import Router from 'next/router'

export default function BackButton() {
    return (
        <div onClick={() => Router.back()}>Go Back</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out, that you may experience odd behaviour on mobile devices if you have `:hover` assigned the element in CSS due to the way onClick is triggered in React on mobile.

Comment: That just hides the exact same line of code.
The link from @Clément is from next 7, v8 did also the same: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/v8.0.4/packages/next-server/lib/router/router.ts#L192

Comment: Well... I don't think this is very a11y friendly...

Comment: @AnatoleLucet very good point, as mentioned, this is the official nextjs example. I know nextjs team likes this kind of feedback, maybe tell them and they will update the documentation. As for this answer, I don't feel like diverging from the official doc to keep things simple

Comment: How can we interrupt the web browser's default back button behavior and have it simply run the Router.back() method instead?

Comment: [From documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook): since Next.js 13.2, on app directory, `useRouter` should be imported from the `next/navigation` package

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking to go back using the web browser native/default back button probably best to look into "window.onpopstate" with something like this -

```
      const handlePopState = useCallback(() => {
        router.push(/*route logic here*/);
      }, [router]);

      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
        
        // Clean up event listener
        return () => window.removeEventListener('popstate', handlePopState);
      }, [handlePopState])
```

More detail on this page - [Want to have an event handler for the browser's back button with next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932918/want-to-have-an-event-handler-for-the-browsers-back-button-with-next-js)

Answer (score 4):

You can try with this

```
const router = useRouter()
const finalSlashIndex = router.asPath.lastIndexOf('/')
const previousPath = router.asPath.slice(0, finalSlashIndex)
return <Link href={previousPath}>Go back</Link>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

This will work. If you use Next > 13 version app router, make sure you import the `useRouter` from `next/navigation`

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

interface Props {
  title: string;
}

const Header = ({ title }: Props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <div className="flex bg-brand-normal py-1 px-3">
      <button onClick={() => router.back()}>
        Back
      </button>
      <div className="grow text-center">
        <h2 className="text-slate-50">{title}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: This solution works, but there's a concern: it may also redirect users to external websites if they directly entered our website URL in the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution will be something like

```
"use client";

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";

interface Props {
  title: string;
}

const Header = ({ title }: Props) => {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const finalSlashIndex = pathname.lastIndexOf('/')
  const previousPathname = pathname.slice(0, finalSlashIndex)
  return (
    <div className="flex bg-brand-normal py-1 px-3">
      <Link href={previousPathname}>
        Back
      </Link>
      <div className="grow text-center">
        <h2 className="text-slate-50">{title}</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```