# How can I use react hooks/context to manage breadcrumbs in my app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm building a web app with Next.js and React.

I'd like to show breadcrumbs and/or "go back" links on a set of pages.

Now, the simplest thing to do would be to render the `<BackButton url="/url/to/go/back/to"/>` component *on* the page where it will be displayed, but for visual/layout reasons, it needs to be rendered *above* that level, in Next's top-level `_app.js` component instead.

**What's the *simplest* way to pass URLs "up" to the top-level app to be used by the back button?**

The ideal pattern seems to be a hook in each page like:

```
useGoBackButton("/url/to/go/back/to")
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how to pass arguments in this way.

React context and `useState()` seems like one approach too, but it feels like overkill - the URL will never change unless the page itself changes, so making it stateful seems like unnecessary overhead? Ideally this would work in a server-rendered way too.

What am I missing?

At the moment I'm using a trick [similar to this](https://reacttricks.com/nested-dynamic-layouts-in-next-apps/) to pass data up to the Next.js `_app` component, but because I need to write the line in the module scope - *outside* the page component function, I can't access props that I often need to generate the correct URL.

```
MyPage.goBackUrl = "/can/only/have/hardcoded/urls/:(
```

I've also tried `window.history.back()`, but the results are too unpredictable. It's important to say exactly which URL we want to go back to.

When I've needed to do similar things in the past with Rails, I've used `<%= yield :head %>` and `<% content_for :head %>` methods, which was clean and simple.

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843119/next-js-react-go-back-to-the-previous-page ?

Comment: yes - `window.history.back()` `Router.back()` etc isn't what i want. i want to explicitly manage this.